# for loops with and without block statements

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I looked for a function to determine if a number is prime and found this

```
for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++)
  if (num % i === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
```

and I don't understand why that works, yet this doesn't

```
for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
  if (num % i === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

What is it about the (lack of the) block statement that is functioning differently

Comment: In the first case, the `return true;` is not executed in the scope of the `for`-loop.

Comment: This highlights why consistent use of blocks makes code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code looks like this:

```
for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++){
  if (num % i === 0) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

Notice how `return true` is on the outside. Your second code doesn't work because it prematurely returns true when there are more numbers to check. Your entire `for` loop is equivalent to

```
return num % 2 !== 0;
```

which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: Got it. Thanks vury musch

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you something about blocks that you might not have known (It took me a while to discover this at least).

When you use a loop or if-else statement, you can ignore the using braces `{` and `}`.

**Example 1**

```
if (a === b){
    c = 0;
}
```

is actually the same as

```
if (a === b)
    c = 0;
```

**Example 2**

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    a += 1;
}
```

is actually the same as

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    a += 1;
```

**However 1**

```
if (a === b){
    c = 0;
    d = 1;
}
```

is *not* the same with

```
if (a === b)
    c = 0;
    d = 1;
```

**However 2**

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    a += 1;
    b += 1;
}
```

is *not* the same with

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    a += 1;
    b += 1;
```

**Explanation**

In loops and if-else statement, the block statement (codes surrounded by `{` and `}` groups the codes within it and execute it.

However, in the absence of `{` and `}`, the loops or if-else statement will only execute the single line of code after it.

Meaning,

```
var a = 0,
    b = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    a += 1;
    b += 1;
```

In this case, `a === 10` but `b === 1`.

Also, in the following case,

```
var a = 0,
    b = 0;
if (false)
    a = 10;
    b = 10;
```

`a === 0` but `b === 10`.